# Central AC is Icing up, but not cooling my house

Tags: hvac

My central air conditioner isn't cooling like it used to. I noticed that the refrigerant lines entering the evaporator coil in the plenum were icing up. What might the problem be?

Comment: Probably it has a leak, so you'd need to find the leak, fix it, and then refill the system. IIRC, icing up with poor cooling is often a sign of low refrigerant - but refrigerant does not GET low without a leak...

Comment: Poor air circulation can freeze a moderately proper charged coil. Change the filter and open more registers. Clean both the coils, at least the outside one with a garden hose. But sorry, 90% chance you're low on gas and that everything I mentioned is just dirty, too.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/43869/33), or [this one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/44735/33), [this one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/48469/33), or maybe even [this one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/8893/33) might be helpful.

Comment: Somewhat counter-intuitive, but low refrigerant in a flooded evaporator system HVAC will cause the acting evaporator to ice up. You have a slow leak, have your HVAC tech come and check the system out.

Answer (score 0):

Chemically clean the evaporator coil with coil cleaner, buy it at an appliance store.is filter ok.buy a cheapie for ac season they flow more air.