# Why is my fridge building ice on the outside but not getting cold inside?

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

My fridge is getting cold enough to quickly produce huge amounts of ice (see picture below) despite being fully defrosted (I used a heat gun) but it can't get below 50° F.  Does it matter that all the ice is concentrated on one side/corner and not over the rest of the coils?

If it matters, I spent a solid 2 hours last night fully unclogging a horribly clogged drain hole. I also put an additional fan inside the fridge, trying to circulate more cold air, but it didn't seem to do much.

Does having ice mean my compressor is working? Could it be an issue with my evaporator?  Would  love ideas of things to check!

**Edit: my Fridge uses R134A**
[image: frozen parts of coil]

Comment: Low coolant: best chioce, if fridge is older than 5 years, is to replace the whole fridge. PS: if on its label is indicated R12 or R134, it cannot be refilled because those gases are outlawed (R12 since '97)

Comment: @DDS, I guess it depends where you live, r22 is still available and sold on the internet for ~400 to 500 per jug. R134 is only 150$ and I have found it as low as 75$ as long as they are available they have not been outlawed. But cannot be imported or manufactured in the U.S. but is not outlawed.

Comment: Edit: my fridge uses R134a

Comment: Here (EU) R22 isn't available since about 5 years, R134 isn't used in refrigerators any more (R600 is most common).

Comment: Since the op is in U.S. it may be worth a service call, example the unit has a service port and the vapor pressure is close to the temp/ pressure chart a simple refill may be about 100. If no port one can be added and then depending on the pressure it may be able to just recharge, if the pressure is low it will need to be pumped down and refilled, I think a friend that repairs fridges charges 25 per pound for r134a time is more expensive. I would expect under 300$ and if a really good guy it may be as low as 100$ but defiantly worth a call. Look for references as there are crooks out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a sure sign that the refrigerant has leaked out. There is just enough left to freeze over the first bit of the coil as the remnants flash vaporize after passing through the expansion valve due to high suction. If a meter set was connected, one would find low high side pressure and high low side pressure.

If it wasn't a high priced refrigerator or is out of warranty, don't bother with a service call, just replace it. Do not attempt to repair it youself unless you have a EPA 608 or 609 license depending on if it is a R410A or R134A unit.

Comment: Hi Dan, could you please source your answer?

Comment: Why would that part be freezing over at all? Wouldn't the fridge be warming up the rest of the coil?  Would I not need to look for the leak?

Comment: I can't give a source. You can refer to any source that explains vapor compression refrigeration. I stated why. Yes, it is. The leak would be hard to find without a electronic leak detector due to the low pressure in the system.

Comment: Okay. In your answer you say "just replace it", what/which part would I replace (or do you mean refill the refrigerant)?

Comment: Contact your local Power Company or government to see if they are doing free or cheap exchanges of old refrigerators. Some power companies do that because the newrefrigerators are so much more efficient than the older ones. Is cheaper for them to subsidize your fridge then build additional generating capacity to power your old

Comment: @wizlog "it" refers to the whole fridge, i.e. unless expensive, it's cheaper to replace than to repair (and may even save on your power bills)

Comment: If you're in the UK you can often find free 2nd hand fridges on freecycle or facebook. People are always throwing them out.

Comment: @ChrisH I shouldn't just have someone refill the R134A? The fridge costs $5100 (it's 36" by 84")

Comment: Repair, not just refill. But that's worth spending money on, unlike a $200 fridge

Comment: a good source of the answer provided by Dan D. is right here on DIY SE: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48450/why-do-the-evaporator-and-suction-lines-freeze-when-there-is-low-refrigerant

Comment: I am sure that my explanation would be correct if only the frosting was occurring on the evaporator but the picture in the question appears to be actually the condenser coil. A situation that could be explained if this refrigerator had a reversing valve to turn it into a heat pump for defrost. It could be that it is stuck defrosting. If you can locate the 4 port valve in that unit and tap it on the end you might be able to fix it at least until its calls for defrost again.